# Three Android apps need to use common libraries. How to share among them all using internal storage only?

Tags: android

For example, let's pretend there are three apps in Google Play named A, B, and C.

If I install C, and C requires a file called `lib.so`, then C will download the file from a given location to internal storage and use it.

Now, I install A and B, and they also require `lib.so`.

How can A and B share the file that C already has, using internal storage only?

Also, if I install B first, then I'd like it to be the same if I install A and C next.

I know it's possible to do this on external storage, but it can be removed by the user, but most importantly some devices don't have external storage.

Is there some way to make a fake external storage on the internal storage that can be shared among apps?

Answer (score 0):

> How can A and B share the file that C already has, using internal storage only?

That's not a good idea, if it is even possible.

If you insist, you can try playing around with `android:sharedUserId` and loading `.so` files from another app's internal storage, but that leads to fragility, and will not work if any of your apps are already on the Play Store (since you cannot change `android:sharedUserId` without breaking all current installations).

> I know it's possible to do this on external storage

Only by idiots. Anyone can replace your `.so` with another one that has malware in it.

Comment: Anyone can replace the files, but you can check for file validity using sha1 or md5 sums, among other methods. Can "external storage" be implemented on internal storage? If so, how?

Comment: @trusktr: "Can "external storage" be implemented on internal storage?" -- no.